# ExtJS TextField values submitted as a string instead of integer/number

Tags: extjs, textfield

I have an Ext Editor Grid with a NumberColumn. The column's editor is set to an Ext.form.TextField. This grid is populated by JSON and data is submitted as JSON.

My problem is that when the user enters a number in this column, it is sent as a string instead of a number. In other words, it looks like this **Property: "500"** and what I want is this, **Property: 500**.

My column definition:

```
new Ext.grid.NumberColumn ({
            header: 'Area (ha)',
            dataIndex: 'Area',
            format: '0',
            width: 60,
            editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                allowBlank: false
            })
        })
```

And the field definition for this column:

```
{ name: 'Area'}
```

I've tried this but it does nothing:

```
{ name: 'Area', type: 'int' }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a resolution. Apparently there's a Ext.form.NumberField. It's not listed in the ExtJS documentation, I had to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

It is also useful to note that in order to actually get typed values out of the form, `getValues` is not suitable.

`Ext.form.Basic` also has a method `getFieldValues` which will return the values as you would want them when POST'ing JSON (or other non-stringified format). This will return `numberfield`s as integers, checkboxes as booleans, etc.

P.S. `getFieldValues` is just a wrapper around `getValues`; it uses the undocumented 4th parameter of it called `useDataValues`, the name of which of course is confusing, not to mention the name `getFieldValues`.